# Can the Process builder, count the number of instances and then execute a certain task

Tags: trigger, process-builder, standard-objects, count

Process automator can be used to automate a lot of things within salesforce. For one such scenario can I use it to count the number of instances of a certain object and then set a checkbox value to true?

Certification sObject(Parent) --> Exam sObject(Child) [Master-Detail-Relationship]

Say a person passes all 4 Exams under a certain Certification, I want the process automator to count the number of passed exams, and if it is 4, set a checkbox in the Certification object to True.

Can this be done without an apex code or trigger?

Comment: Is it a master detail relationship?  Do you try to create a Roll Up function in the Master and test it using Process Builder?

Comment: it is Master-Detail-Relationship Yes. No i did not try the roll up function. I will do some research and try that out.

Comment: Another option is to create a flow to count the number of children. Call the flow from the process builder.

Comment: can this count the number of children with certain properties, in my case, children with "passed" as a value in a field

Comment: @NivethKumar : yes

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this documentation, you cannot use a Roll Up formula field because it will calculate after the insert or Update ([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)).

So, the solution without code:

1. Create a flow that there the ParentID as an input variable and make your
   logic in the flow
2. Create a Process Builder.
3. *Use No criteria—just execute the actions!* on Decision option.
4. Call the Flow sending the Parent ID (stored in child record) in the *Immediate
   Action* option

It will run only if the Parent never changes. If the Parent could change, you will call the flow two times, using the Old and the New value. For that, you will need to use a formula field to send the ID to the flow.

Another option is to create two formula fields

1. A Roll Up formula field to count
2. A Formula field testing the Roll Up result. If it is equal or more than 4, the Certification approval is True, else it is False.

Comment: The roll up formula worked, thanks alot. I used the count function to get the number of child records, then filtered it using the criteria method to get the people who passed.

Comment: Good to know that I helped you!